# How do I create a new development environment for a Sitecore project already in production?

Tags: sitecore

My coworker and I are taking over a Sitecore project that was built by some other entity and is currently in production. What's the process for creating a local development environment so we can begin making changes?

Comment: Do you have the source for the site?

Comment: @marto I'm not really sure- I only have access to what's on the production server. Should all the source files I need be there?

Comment: Usually you would only have compiled assemblies on the production server. Are there any .cs files on the server? They might be running it as a Website project rather than a Web Application in which case you'll have the source there.

Comment: @marto code files are included for controls and sublayouts at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach is to completely duplicate everything from prod. That usually involves:

- Go on the prod server and zip up the site's root. The IIS website will point to a "website" folder. In addition, you'll want the site's "data" folder, which is usually one folder above the "website" so its not web-accessible. The data folder contains the license, logs, etc.
- In SQL management stuido, make a backup of the Core, Master, and Web databases for the site. They're listed in the `/Website/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config` file. There may be more databases for Sitecore modules that you need
- Pull the site zip and databases locally and re-configure them on your local machine. Some key setting you'll need to update your local environment are

  - Settings in the `/Website/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config` for local data sources
  - The `web.config`'s `dataFolder` setting which maps the path on the file system to the data folder

Answer (score 0):

Once you get everything duplicated locally(following Mark's steps ) I usually remove the web database reference from the web.config and change all references of "web" to "master". It's easier to develop this way as sitecore is running in live mode and you don't have to worry about publishing.

My usually folder structure for a sitecore project is

- sampleproject

  - lib

    - sitecore - which contains all the sitecore sold
  - src

    - data - datafolder stuff goes here
    - website

On post build I copy all the dlls from /lib/sitecore to the bin folder.